# Functions with graph vertix

Tags: functions, graphs-and-networks

I am new to Mathematica, trying to use it to study network structure. I am having trouble with creating this code.

Here are the steps I need to do:

- First, generate a graph. Let's say a regular graph with 10 vertices and degree 5. Since the RegularGraph command is no longer usable (Combinatorica has been replaced), I had to make do with

```
RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[ConstantArray[5, 10]]]
```

Is there any better suggestion?

- Second, create a dataset. For simplicity:

```
d = Tuples[{1, 2}, 10]
```

- Third, assign the value in each row of the above dataset to the vertice in the graph. This is where I got stuck. I could not find any documentation regarding this issue. Since I might not have been clear on what I want to do, I will give an example. In the above graph, we have 10 vertices. Let's call the 10 vertices x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10. The first row of my created dataset has the value:

```
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

So I want to set x1=1,x2=1,...,x10=1.

- Finally, do an function on the vertice given their connection. For example, in the above graph, since x1, x2, x3 are connected, I want to create a function f(x1)=x1+x2+x3. I have no clue on how to do this part as well.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Wouldn't you want RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[ConstantArray[5, 10]]] for a 10 node regular graph with degree 5?

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it

Comment: Make sure you check out her help guides it the help documentation, particularly:  guide/GraphConstructionAndRepresentation  
guide/GraphPropertiesAndMeasurements  guide/GraphsAndMatrices

Comment: AdjacencyMatrix[graph]  might be useful.

Answer (score 5):

First we create the graph and as the graph has 10 vertices, 10 tuples:

```
gr = RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[ConstantArray[5, 10]]]
d = Take[Tuples[{1, 2}, 4], 10]
```

[image]

Then we assign the tuples to vertices:

```
Graph[gr, VertexLabels -> Table[i -> ToString@d[[i]], {i, 10}]]
```

[image]

Finally we get the adjacency matrix:

```
AdjacencyMatrix[gr] // MatrixForm
```

[image]